# How can a class label be extracted from the filename returned by tf.WholeFileReader.read() in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a bunch of images organized in subdirectories, which correspond to the class labels of the image. E.g.

- images/1/0000001.jpg, images/1/0000002.jpg, ... for class 1 images
- images/2/0123456.jpg, images/2/0123457.jpg, ... for class 2 images

Now, I was wondering how I could get the integer class label when using the `tf.WholeFileReader()` which has the `read` method that yields the file name as a tensor. Outside the graph, I could simply do a `int('images/2/0123457.jpg'.split('/')[1])` to get the integer label, but how do I do it inside the graph so that I can use the labels for model training? Below is a naive example, and I am basically looking for the solution to `class_label = ... # get class label from file_name` in this example below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        tf.train.match_filenames_once('images/*/*.jpg'))

    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

    file_name, image_raw = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
    file_name = tf.identity(file_name, name='file_name')

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_raw, name='image')
    class_label = ... # get class label from file_name



with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:

    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    image_tensor = sess.run('image:0')
    print('Image shape:', image_tensor.shape)

    file_name = sess.run('file_name:0')
    print('File name:', file_name)    

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution to my question using `tf.split_string` and `tf.string_to_number`:

```
class_label = tf.string_split([file_name], '/').values[1]
class_label = tf.string_to_number(class_label, tf.int32)
```